# Pythonanywhere is giving NOREVERSEMATCH at/blog but the localhost is working perfectly

Tags: python, html, django

PythonAnywhere is giving `NOREVERSEMATCH` at `/blog` but the locahost is working perfectly.

I have gone and resaved the project and committed it again to GitHub as well as pulling it on PythonAnywhere. But is still not working. I tried to reload it but is still doing the same.

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user\\/(?P<username>[^/]+)\\/profile\\/$']
```

Comment: You are not logged in at the remote site, I take it? What happens if you logout on localhost? Do you get the same error then?

Comment: I haven’t thought about that but it could be the problem, let me log out from the local host and see, I will be right back.

Comment: Yes you’re right, I just logged out of the localhost and the error occurred. I will like a situation where people don’t have to be logged in to see the page or the authors profile, how do I achieve that please! I also added a view on the post for when people click the url, I will also like the view to update even if the viewer is anonymous. I know am asking a lot of questions, I’m sorry for the stress, I started learning programming on February 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to link to a logged in user's profile - even if there is no logged in user.

In general you solve the problem like this:

```html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div>Hi user {{user.username }}!</div>
{% else %}
    <div><a href="{% url 'account-login' %}">Login here</a></div>
{% endif %}
```

This assumes that your context processors in `settings.py` contain [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates):

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",  # <=========== that must be there
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The documentation page linked above, has a lot of examples and background information about working with users.